# My ubuntu laptop connects to my mobile hotspot but doesn't connect to home wifi neither 2.4hz nor 5 hz

Tags: wireless

My laptop connects and works perfectly with my mobile phone hotspot but doesn't connect to home wifi fiber .

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run "lsb_release -a"